# Apache RewriteRule issue in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have to redirect permanently all the URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/?par=1248 (with and without the www)
```

to

```
http://www.example.com
```

using .htaccess file.

The placeholders I used above, "par" and "1248", could be anything (char(s), number(s), ..)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you and redirect the urls you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much for your precious answer.

Comment: No problem, feel free to make the answer as correct so other users who have the same problem as you will know how you solved your problem.